Azure CLI update metric alert with custom properties
I have a series of metric alerts in azure that I would like to add custom properties to the action group.
I have manually added some test data to one of the alerts, and when I use the CLI to pull the details for this alert I can see the data in the returned JSON :
az monitor metrics alert show --resource-group 'MyGroup' --name 'MyAlert'
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "actionGroupId": "/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/MyGroup/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/MyAlert",
      "webHookProperties": {
        "ResourceName": "MyResourceName",
        "TestData": "test"
      }
    }
  ],

I am trying to add similar data to other alerts using the update command, but I cant see any examples of how to add these WebHookProperties to existing alerts.
az monitor metrics alert update --resource-group --name 'MyAlert' --add actions ['Test','Test']

Any help is much appreciated!


I am trying to add similar data to other alerts using the update command, but I cant see any examples of how to add these WebHookProperties to existing alerts.

Here is the cmd to update the WebHookProperties to existing alert.
az monitor metrics alert update --resource-group 'RG-Name' --name 'MyAlert' --set actions[0].webHookProperties='{"ResourceName": "Venkat", "TestData": "Test"}'

Output:

After running the above command, the WebHookProperties are displayed using the cmd below.
 az monitor metrics alert show --resource-group 'RG-Name' --name 'MyAlert'


Reference: az monitor metrics alert update

When I try this command, I get the following output : Expect <class 'dict'>, got {ResourceName: Venkat, TestData: Test} (<class 'str'>)

Changing the --set values to this works :
--set actions[0].webHookProperties="{'TestData': 'Test'}"
I changed the quotes to have double on the outside, and single on the variables.
